# pip install twisted returns [WinError 87] while executing command python setup.py egg_info

Tags: python-3.x, twisted

I am installing scrapy after anaconda installed. Neither pip nor anaconda environments can successfully get it installed. After looking into log I found it is twisted that error comes from.

After googling for days I can't find any clue to help me out.

Can someone help on this?

Anaconda: 3 2018.12 x64
Python: 3.7.1

2019-03-09T11:02:18   Downloading from URL https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5d/0e/a72d85a55761c2c3ff1cb968143a2fd5f360220779ed90e0fadf4106d4f2/Twisted-18.9.0.tar.bz2#sha256=294be2c6bf84ae776df2fc98e7af7d6537e1c5e60a46d33c3ce2a197677da395 (from https://pypi.org/simple/twisted/)
2019-03-09T11:02:21   Added Twisted from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5d/0e/a72d85a55761c2c3ff1cb968143a2fd5f360220779ed90e0fadf4106d4f2/Twisted-18.9.0.tar.bz2#sha256=294be2c6bf84ae776df2fc98e7af7d6537e1c5e60a46d33c3ce2a197677da395 to build tracker 'C:\Users\accounts\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-tracker-_88mv767'
2019-03-09T11:02:21     Running setup.py (path:C:\Users\accounts\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1c5b5j57\Twisted\setup.py) egg_info for package Twisted
2019-03-09T11:02:21     Running command python setup.py egg_info
2019-03-09T11:02:21     Error [WinError 87] The parameter is incorrect while executing command python setup.py egg_info
2019-03-09T11:02:21 Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [WinError 87] The parameter is incorrect

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `pip install twisted --user`?

Comment: yes, same error.